# How does one add a <div> above a hidden <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a new `div` before the hidden div `ValidationSummary1`

```js
var existingNode = document.getElementById('ValidationSummary1')
var addin = document.createElement('div')
addin.innerHTML = "Hello World!"
existingNode.insertBefore(addin,existingNode[0])
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="ValidationSummary1" class="Error" style="color:Red;display:none;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `existingNode[0]` -> `existingNode`

Comment: What if you `setAttribute` of your existing node to visible then do `insertBefore` and set the visibility to none again after your insertion?

Comment: You are almost there. All you have to do is update your existing node to `var existingNode = document.getElementById('ValidationSummary1').parentNode;` since you want the parent and then use `insertBefore` as existingNode.insertBefore(addin, existingNode.firstChild);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the attribute `id` to the element using which you can set the `textContent` property. You also have to target the `parentNode` of the newly inserted node:

```js
var existingNode = document.getElementById('ValidationSummary1');
var addin = document.createElement('div');
addin.id = 'newDiv';
existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(addin,existingNode);
document.getElementById('newDiv').textContent = 'hello world';
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="ValidationSummary1" class="Error" style="color:Red;display:none;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For [`.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) to work, you need to reference the parent node instead

> The `Node.insertBefore()` method inserts a node before a reference node as a child of a specified parent node.

```
var existingNode = document.getElementById('ValidationSummary1')
var addin = document.createElement('div');
existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(addin,existingNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the parent Div first to append.

**JS**

```
 var parentDiv = document.getElementById("ValidationSummary1").parentElement;    
 parentDiv.innerHTML += '<div id="newID"></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with `.insertBefore()`**

```js
var existingNode = document.getElementById('ValidationSummary1').parentNode; // Selects the parent node of hidden div
var addin = document.createElement('div')
addin.innerHTML = 'hello world';
existingNode.insertBefore(addin, existingNode.firstChild); // inserting adding before firstchild of existingNode
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="ValidationSummary1" class="Error" style="color:Red;display:none;">
      Hidden Content
    </div>
</div>
```